# Problema desconocido con syntaxis de funciones de python

Tags: python

Hice este programa para pasar de m/s a km/h (entre otras cosas) para automatizar los cálculos de un trabajo y ayer funcionaba. ¡¡¡El caso es que ya no y no entiendo qué puede haber cambiado si ni lo he tocado!!!

¿Qué le pasa?

```
def op1():
    n1 = float(input("introduce la velocidad (sin la unidad m/s):"))
    np = float(n1 * 3600)
    result = float(np/1000) 
    print("El resultado en km/h es:")
    print(result)
```

Yo no le veo nada... Tuve un fallo similar hace poco en el mismo programa, y lo solucioné especificando las variables como floats, pero ahora...

Editado: Lo he vuelto a probar, esta vez el .py original con la CMD y no el convertido en .exe, y este funciona. ¿Alguna idea? He utilizado auto-pip-to-exe en la CMD, no nada externo.

Comment: ¿Qué problema te da? porque el codigo no tiene nada raro. solo tienes que llamar a continuación a la función con `op1()` para que funcione.

Comment: Todo pareciera estar en orden... Sin detalles del error/comportamiento deseado/comportamiento actual no podemos saber que está pasando.

Comment: Ya... No dice nada, solo se cierra. Pero solo es en el .exe convertido, que pasa esto. No en el .py original. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: Nunca llamas a la funcion `op1()`, por eso _se sale_ sin hacer nada, pues el programa está prácticamente vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Ha simple vista todo parece estar bien... Aunque *puede* que tu problema se origine en "n1" ya que si la entrada es " "(***nula***/***vacia***) o contiene una letra (string), te dará el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Esto lo puedes solucionar mediante este bloque de codigo:

```
Python 3.8.3
def op1():
    while True:
        try:
            n1 = float(input("introduce la velocidad (sin la unidad m/s):"))
            break
        except: # Puedes capturar todas las excepciones o solo: ValueError o TypeError
            print("Ingrese una opcion valida")  # En vez de un print simplemente puedes poner un pass 
    np = float(n1) * 3600
    result = float(np/1000) 
    print("El resultado en km/h es:")
    print(result)
op1()
```

No te olvides de llamar a la función..

Cualquier cosa me dices ;)

Comment: Gracias, peroese non es el problema. Ya fui con cuidado de especificar siempre los tipos de variables, y ese no es el mensaje de error. De hecho, todo va bien. Solo es que al convertirlo a .exe, se cierra automáticamente, y este es el trozo de código donde he aislado el fallo. Muchas gracias de todas formas. saludos!